# Linking data within MySQL tables into 1 table with PHP Code

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Background info:
I am trying to create a digital job raising system. Admin raises a job sheet and pulls in a client from "tblclient" table, fills out the details of the job and then assigns the job sheet to a employee user.

With this being said I am having difficulty pulling data from the clients table and users table then linking them to a row in the jobs table. I am new to PHP coding and am unsure how to script it out so my user can select the client and all the client details are attached to the job sheet and then coding it so the job sheet can be moved around between users.

This is so that when the job is complete the Admin can preview the job sheet with all the client details on it, job details and print with all the information on screen.

Is there any tutorials I can use for this procedure?

Notes:
I currently have a form that will insert the job data into the job table, I just don't know what code to use to pull in users/clients and link it to that specific job.

Thanks

```
<?php 
include 'core/init.php'; 
include 'include/overall/overall_header.php'; 
protect_page();
admin_protect();
$today_date = date("Y-m-d");

?>

<div id="container">
<div id="content-container">
<div id="sidenav">
    <?php include 'include/sidenav.php'; ?>

</div>
<div id="content">

<h1>Add a new job</h1>

<?php echo $today_date; ?>

<?php

if (isset($_GET['success']) && empty($_GET['success'])) {
echo 'Job added successfully!';
} else {
if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) {
    $job_data = array(
        'date'                  => $_POST['date'],
        'description'           => $_POST['description'],
        'artworkbrief'          => $_POST['artworkbrief'],
        'extracosts'            => $_POST['extracosts'],
        'stock1'                => $_POST['stock1'],
        'orderno1'              => $_POST['orderno1'],
        'ordered1'              => $_POST['ordered1'],
        'stock2'                => $_POST['stock2'],
        'orderno2'              => $_POST['orderno2'],
        'ordered2'              => $_POST['ordered2'],
        'stock3'                => $_POST['stock3'],
        'orderno3'              => $_POST['orderno3'],
        'ordered3'              => $_POST['ordered3'],
        'subtotal'              => $_POST['subtotal'],
        'extracosts1'           => $_POST['extracosts1'],
        'total'                 => $_POST['total']
    );
    raise_job($job_data);
    header('Location: raise_job.php');
    exit();

}
}

?>

<select id="clientname" name="clientname">
<?php
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=formation_ims', 'root',         'form8tion');
    #Set Error Mode to ERRMODE_EXCEPTION.
    $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('Select clientname from tblclients');
    $stmt->execute();
       while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<option>'.$row['clientname'].'</option>';
    }
?>
</select> 

<div id="job-sheet">
<form action="" method="post">
<div class="row-3">
    <div class="description">
        <p>Description:</p>
        <textarea type="text" name="description"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row-4">
    <div class="artwork-brief">
        <p>Artwork Brief:</p>
        <textarea type="text" name="artworkbrief"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row-5">
    <div class="extra-costs-container">
        <div class="extra-costs">
            <p>Extra Costs:</p>
            <textarea type="text" name="extracosts"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="total-container">
        <div class="sub-total">
            Sub Total:
            <input type="text" name="subtotal">
        </div>   
    </div>  
    <div class="extra-num-container">
        <div class="extra-costs-num">
            Extra Costs:
            <input type="text" name="extracosts1">
        </div>    
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row-6">
    <div class="stock-material-container">
        <div class="stock-material">
        <p>Stock/Material:</p>
            <div class="stock-material-row">
                <div class="stock-material-col01">
                    <input type="text" name="stock1">
                </div>    
                <div class="stock-material-col02">
                    Order No.<input type="text" name="orderno1">
                </div>    
                <div class="stock-material-col03">
                    Ordered:<input type="checkbox" name="ordered1">
                </div>    
            </div>
            <div class="stock-material-row">
                    <div class="stock-material-col01">
                        <input type="text" name="stock2">
                    </div>    
                    <div class="stock-material-col02">
                        Order No.<input type="text" name="orderno2">
                    </div>    
                    <div class="stock-material-col03">
                        Ordered:<input type="checkbox" name="ordered2">
                    </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="stock-material-row">
            <div class="stock-material-col01">
                <input type="text" name="stock3">
            </div>    
            <div class="stock-material-col02">
                Order No.<input type="text" name="orderno3">
            </div>    
            <div class="stock-material-col03">
                Ordered:<input type="checkbox" name="ordered3">
            </div>  
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="total-container">
        <div class="sub-total">
            Sub Total:
            <input type="text" name="subtotal">
        </div>   
    </div>  
    <div class="extra-num-container">
        <div class="extra-costs-num">
            Extra Costs:
            <input type="text" name="extracosts1">
        </div>    
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>

<?php include 'include/overall/overall_footer.php'; ?>
```

ahh yes, I understand what this code is doing but not familiar with the syntax. I got an error:
   Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in...
I think you left out an ")" but even after reinstating it, my dropdown menu isn't populated:

```
<select name='clientid'>
<?php
    $query="SELECT * FROM tblclients";
    $result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo "<option value='".$row['Client_ID']."'>".stripslashes($row['ClientName']."     </option>";
    }
?>
```

`

Comment: Please, paste your current code and explain exactly what is not working as expected.

Comment: @enenen I have updated. I styled my table with div's as you can see.

Answer (score 0):

When inputting your job, you will want a field in your form containing clientid and another containing userid. The following is an example of how that might be done.

```
<select name='clientid'>
    <?php
        $query="SELECT * FROM ClientTable";
        $result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
            echo "<option value='".$row['ClientID']."'>".stripslashes($row['ClientName']."</option>";
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Then when you want to output the job with all it's information, when you run the query you should use the `LEFT JOIN` command, for example

```
$query="SELECT * FROM JobTable
    LEFT JOIN UserTable ON UserTable.UserID=JobTable.UserID
    LEFT JOIN ClientTable ON ClientTable.ClientID=JobTable.ClientID
    WHERE JobID='".mysql_real_escape_string($jobid)."'";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

That grabs the appropriate client and user informations by their IDs (which I hope you've set up with auto-increment by the way)

Comment: Ok, so how would I populate a dropdown menu for the user to see? So the Admin can select a clientname which is connected to the query? I apologise for my lack of knowledge on this, it has totally fragged my mind trying to figure it all out.

Comment: @Orion I've added more information to the answer for inputting.

Comment: Ah, now you've posted your code, I see you're using PDO, some ideas will be transferable, but I write use mysql as you can see.

Comment: ahh yes, I understand what this code is doing but not familiar with the syntax. I got an error:

Comment: Apologies I broke the code down to understand, the drop down menu works now & I will now attempt the query to insert it into the database.

Comment: @Orion As you're using PDO for your inserts, keep using PDO. See if you can try and get something out of the documentation http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php
or a tutorial http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers